# Where is the docker file located?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have pulled an image from the docker hub. I want to modify the docker file for this image. Where is the docker file located on my Machine? Thanks.

Comment: From the docker hub, you should be able to find out home page of the docker image which is either hosted in a code repository such as github or gitlab. From the code repository, you can find out the DockerFile. Just copy it to your local and modify.

Answer (score 7):

The Dockerfile isn't on your machine.  Once the image is built, it exists independently of the Dockerfile, just like a compiled C program doesn't need its source code kept around to function.  You can partially recover the Dockerfile via the [`docker history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) command, but this won't show you files added with `ADD` or `COPY`, and various "image squishing" programs can further obfuscate things.  The recommended way to get an image's Dockerfile is to go to the repository from which the image was built (hopefully linked from the image's Docker Hub page).  If there's no public repository, you're out of luck.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, I'm a noob in this.
Pulling an image alone is going to download the image alone, without the supplementary files. If you need those, please go to the Github webpage where the image is (if you got it from Github), then push clone or download button on the right. If you have no access to webpages (on a VM for instance), install 'developer tools' and then write 'git clone ' where  is the link that appears after pressing clone or download.
If you check the directory where you cloned the link, you'll find all the files you need.

Comment: I guess this comment is not helpful and doesn't answer the question.